# How to interface with opentsdb from Python

Tags: python, opentsdb

I'd like to interface with an opentsdb data store with Python. I only see a java client library for it. How would I go about this?

Comment: I've never used this and don't understand half the jargon behind it, but google turned up a few promising links: [1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opentsdb/W2LvsEigoiI) [2](https://github.com/OpenTSDB/tcollector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give that library a try.

Twisted Python OpenTSDB Client

http://code.google.com/p/totsdb/source/browse/tostdb.py

Comment: The link did not appear valid - maybe the project moved?  It appears this https://github.com/lexh/totsdb has the latest code

Answer (score 4):

Unless you want a standalone client (in which case the Twisted Python OpenTSDB Client looks great), the easiest way is to run [tcollector](https://github.com/OpenTSDB/tcollector), and simply drop your Python script under `/usr/local/tcollector/collector/0` – your script is expected to never return and print one data point per line in that format: `metric timestamp value tag1=value1 tag2=value2 ...`.

tcollector takes care of connecting to OpenTSDB, pushing your data points out, etc.  So you can focus on collecting the data you want to collect and write your data collection script in Python or any other scripting language you may like.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Python request module](http://docs.python-requests.org/) and [OpenTSDB HTTP API](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/), too.